# windbg readmem error: Unable to read data for xxx, load is incomplete

Tags: windbg

I'm using VMWare on Mac, and I have a shared folder z:\shm

When I try to read that file with windbg, it raise an error,

```
0:000> .readmem z:\\shm\\msgbox.bin @$t8 L272
Reading 272 bytes
Unable to read data for 00020000, load is incomplete
```

How can I find out why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the file has only 272 and not 0x272 bytes in length. Use the decimal number format `0n` to fix it:

```
.readmem z:\\shm\\msgbox.bin @$t8 L0n272
```